# Is it possible to program privacy-oriented software using Electron?

Tags: security, electron, privacy

As part of a small research project, I have to create a program using the Electron framework (https://electronjs.org/ and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_(software_framework)). The problem is that this program will manage very private information from other people. These people have presented me some concerns about the Chromium frontend used by Electron, and the possibility that Electron is bundled with Chrome binaries (not open source).

How can I determine if the program I develop with Electron is not sending private information to Google servers or any other third party. Can it be determined if the application is accessing information without the user knowing about it?

In other words: Has Electron be verified to be reliable in terms of privacy and security of information? Of course, I understand there could be security vulnerabilities, like in any other software. My question is more oriented to intentional privacy vulnerabilities, i.e., the developers of Electron have taken the necessary measures to guarantee safety and privacy?

I beg you to avoid opinion-based information, and try to present verifiable facts, e.g., results of tests that have been applied to the framework, independent revisions made by reliable third parties, official statements of security companies, standard test I can run by myself on Electron, etc.

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: This question is maybe better asked on [Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) or [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/). If you do so, please remove the question here to avoid double postings.

Comment: "Electron is bundled with Chrome binaries (not open source)" If it were true electron itself couldn't have MIT licence. Chromium itself is open-source, too. Electron _builds_ chromium from source.

Comment: Aside from inspecting the source, try running it with something like little snitch active - they will let you see exactly what requests it makes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. I like @pergy 's comment. I think it sort of answers my question. At least makes me more comfortable about using Electron-based software.

Comment: I any case, as for @colidyre 's suggestion, I am posting the question on https://security.stackexchange.com/ (Security).